# Find the value of $k$ for given series

Tags: sequences-and-series

[image]

Please give me some hint about this particular question. I am not able to inititae it.

Comment: I think first we need to do it for small values and then see the pattern

Comment: Hint: If $s=a+b=2015$ then $$\frac1{2^a+\sqrt{2^s}}+\frac1{2^b+\sqrt{2^s}}=\frac{(2^{a/2}+2^{b/2})^2}{2^{a/2}(2^{a/2}+2^{b/2})2^{b/2}(2^{b/2}+2^{a/2})}=\frac{2^{a/2}+2^{b/2}}{2^{a/2}2^{b/2}}=\frac1{2^{a/2}}+\frac1{2^{b/2}}.$$

Comment: I stand corrected (well, sit).

Comment: Combine the first and the last term. Second term and the second last term  and so on and see what you get.

Comment: I am removing my embarrassing comments. I have discovered that wine and mathematics don't mix well...

Comment: @Did Should't we get $\frac{1}{2^{a/2}.2^{b/2}}$?

Comment: @H.P.Das Should we? Why?

Comment: @Did Because $(2^{a/2}+2^{b/2})^2$ will get cancelled not $(2^{a/2}+2^{b/2})$ only

Comment: @Did Also could you please put your comment as answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Oops, you are right... Sorry for the misleading part--but it seems that you can now reach a full answer, so you might want to post one on your own.